# How to reslove TypeScript Interface heavy load?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type ItemProps = {
  a: string;
  b?: boolean;
  c?: string; 
}

const arr: ItemProps[] = [
 {
   a: 'demo',
   b: true,
   c: 'test'
 },
 {
   a: 'demo2'
 }
];
```

How to define `ItemProps` that if prop `b` existed. If prop `b` existed prop `c` must be defined？

I want this:

```
const arr: ItemProps[] = [
 {
   a: 'demo',
   b: true,
   c: 'test'
 },
 {
   a: 'demo2',
   b: true, // ERROR, because b exist，but c undefined
 }
];
```

Comment: I'd suggest after creating new object, run a check and verify if rules are met.

Comment: export interface ItemProps {
  a: string;
  b?: boolean | null;
  c?: string | null;
}

Comment: @RaviAshara that's not what op wants

Comment: Don't do this. This breaks the [Liscov subsitution Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Just because you can, doesn't mean you should

Comment: @liam no it does not. `{ a, b, c }` is a valid substitute for `{ a }`

Comment: yes `{ a, b, c }` is a valid substitute of `{ a }` but `{ a }` is NOT a valid substitute of `{a , b, c }`. If OP was only accessing `a` this would be fine, but they want to use `b` and `c` depending on whether they exist or not. This breaks LSP. You might be able to make it work, but you shouldn't

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I don't understand in typescript. If it's typed, then it should be typed and obey SOLID like a typed language. There are too many weird half way houses that just make for bad code

Comment: @liam I don't get your point. Narrowing to a subtype is a common operation in OOP, there's a reason why every language has some form of instanceof operator and possibility for downcasting. Also taking some 20 year old principles and blindly applying them to a 10 year old language doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Sure lets throw all software theory out of the window because not trendy... Good luck with that

Answer (score 2):

Use a union type:

```
type ItemProps = { a: string; } & ({} | { b: boolean;  c: string; });
```

With this Typescript already narrows down the union type with type guards, like e.g.:

```
let item: ItemProps = { a: "test", b: true };

if("b" in item) {
  type Narrowed = typeof item;
  console.log(item.c)
} else {
  type Narrowed = typeof item;
  console.log(item.c); // ERROR
}
```

However, unfortunately sometimes Typescript allows specifying more properties than the type actually has, when the type is a union type this seems to be the case. So although with a union type the typing is more accurate, during creation of new ItemProps it'll not help you.

For that you would need a *discriminated union*, e.g. if two different string literal types get used for the shared property `a`:

```
type ItemProps = { a: "without" } | { a: "with", b: boolean;  c: string; };
```

With that, when assigning an object literal, the union is discriminated to one of the object types based on a, and then only known properties can be specified:

```
type ItemProps = { a: "without" } | { a: "with", b: boolean;  c: string; };

const arr: ItemProps[] = [
 {
   a: 'with',
   b: true,
   c: 'test'
 },
 {
   a: 'without',
   b: true, // ERROR
 },
 {
   a: 'with', // ERROR
 }
];
```

Having such a discriminating property is very useful in many situations, e.g. in conditional logic, so you might want to add such a property to your data model.

```
if(item.a === "with") {
  console.log(item.b, item.c); // works, as item got narrowed down
}
```

Comment: Actually，this can't work.   [See](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsAKAnA9mAzlAvFA3lAIYBcUmwKAlgHYDmA3FAL5QBkUAFPqwD4FQARmUFo0AGwhEaTKAGMyFavSbMAlAwBQmuWhoViKFGTiJUGTAG0AuriiXNBR1GJkA5ABNEaNwBpnQmSUAK4Q-i7y7vAUbo7M4fgBpFCe3gBMfgHCUCFhcZrWWkA)

Comment: Ah, my bad, thought Typescript would behave differently in that situation. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do it like that with an interface. You can check it in your code before adding the data. An attribute can have multiple interfaces.

For example:

> const someItem: InterfaceA | InterfaceB | undefined;

You can check then before updating the value with

```js
if(b) 
{
  someItem = value structured as InterfaceA 
}
else {
  someItem = value structured as InterfaceB
}
```

You can take a look also on how to use classes and constructors https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, guys. I have get the answer!

```
type ExcludeKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: never; };

type RequireOrExcludeKeys<T, Keys extends keyof T = keyof T> = Pick<T,Exclude<keyof T, Keys>> & (Required<Pick<T, Keys>> | ExcludeKeys<Pick<T, Keys>>);

type ItemProps = RequireOrExcludeKeys<{
   a: string;
   b?: boolean;
   c?: string;
}, 'b' | 'c'>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDSEQGcA8AKgHxQC8UA3lANoAKUAlgHZQDWOA9gGZSEC6ALijMIANwgAnANxQAvgFgAUMtCQoAJQgBHFI0kQA8pPjJ0WHAUIAaKNjxQIcYBGZpc7Lr0LlPIHnykZMpQoVB0jAhsRLamqBj4HP7etva4xMQhYQBkUAAUWrr6EGj4EVExdpYZUAA+sIjxFnhlkdE2VXgZAJTKquDQAJIuALZ0kpxgHhSFegbGceZp+JRZoQCGwrjAkiwA5tJrUABGAPxbO-uHSmFQCOdQ27vMB8pytgDkxx91UB8IH0yKmBCE4zG2UHWkkkwmGEDGEymNH4vhoR1WN1uYU2fwwI04H2sR1ux2EOxQECJmKxd2EHxc2w+R3e6OJ2LpeM4AGZCcyqbcMTSNhz4ZwAEyEqAAeilUEA3j6AaPVAKVGgExUwAw-4ADtUAXHKADW1ABTqx0AejqAcgM1YAxeUA9GaALn9AIg6CDZoQQHLQTOp8mU-GkQA)